# Method of Abstract Class used by derived Class

Tags: c++

I got an Abstract Baseclass which looks like this:

```
class AbstractClass {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractClass() = 0 {}
    std::string GetName() const { return m_Name; }
private:
    std::string m_Name;
};
```

Now I got many derived Classes and I want to implement them like this

```
class DerivedClass1 : public AbstractClass{
public:
    DerivedClass1() = default;
    ~DerivedClass1() = default;
private:
    std::string m_Name = "DerivedClass1";
};


int main() {
    DerivedClass1 class1;
    std::cout << class1.GetName();

    return 0;
}
```

I dont want to override GetName() everytime i derive a Class, is this possible?
Edit:
I got a Linker Error. Error LNK2019.

Comment: yes it is possible, just do it. Not clear what is the problem/question. If you did encounter problems you have to tell

Comment: pure abstract destructor?

Comment: Woops. I forgot to add that I am getting a LinkerError... ErrorCode 2019.

Comment: hum after inspecting your code I realized what your "problem" is. You seem to be under the impression that you could override class members. Please read about [the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and explain what you actually want to achieve

Comment: @MarekR Yes I somewhere read that its possible and I clearly dont want to make GetName virtual.

Comment: @HenningWilmer this was rhetorical question, it explains linking issue, [see this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-destructor-c/)

Comment: Anyway I can see that people jump on this dtor issue and didn't noticed that in your code string matches class name. So it looks like this is XY problem (I voted up user463035818) and I wait for X problem exponentiation.

Comment: It's worth mentioning (although probably not your primary issue) that `DerivedClass1 class1; std::cout << class1.GetName();` does not use dynamic dispatch (i.e. doesn't care about whether your functions are `virtual`/polymorphic/overriden anywhere). You need a pointer or a reference to use virtual functions properly (read up on dynamic vs static type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only one name, in the base class, and a constructor with a parameter:

```
class AbstractClass{
public:
   AbstractClass(const std::string& name) : m_Name(name){}
   std::string GetName() const { return m_Name; }
private:
   std::string m_Name;
};



DerivedClass1 : public AbstractClass{
public:
   DerivedClass() : AbstractClass("DerivedClass1") {}
};


int main(){
   DerivedClass1 class1;
   std::cout << class1.GetName();

    return 0;
}
```

There seems to be no reason for making the base class abstract, but if you *do* need that, even a pure virtual destructor must have a definition, or you will get a linker error, because it's needed when destroying derived objects.
Also, if the destructor didn't exist, when would `m_Name` be destroyed?

```
class Abstract
{
public: 
    virtual ~Abstract() = 0;
};

Abstract::~Abstract() {}
```

This makes a class that can't be instantiated, but whose derived classes can still be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you "override" `GetName()`. You can either make `GetName()` virtual and override it in your derived classes:

```
class AbstractClass {
public:
   virtual ~AbstractClass() = default;
   virtual std::string GetName() const { return "AbstractClass"; }
private:
   std::string m_Name;
};
```

and:

```
class DerivedClass1 : public AbstractClass {
public:
   DerivedClass() = default;
   std::string GetName() const override { return "DerivedClass1"; }
};
```

---

Or you can set `m_Name` in your derived classes by passing it to the base class constructor:

```
class AbstractClass {
public:
   AbstractClass(const std::string& name) : m_Name(name) {}
   virtual ~AbstractClass() = default;
   std::string GetName() const { return m_Name; }
protected: // protected not private
   std::string m_Name;
};
```

and:

```
class DerivedClass1 : public AbstractClass {
public:
   DerivedClass() : AbstractClass("DerivedClass1") {}
};
```

---

Or you can set it in the derived's class constructor:

```
class AbstractClass {
public:
   virtual ~AbstractClass() = default;
   std::string GetName() const { return m_Name; }
protected: // protected not private
   std::string m_Name;
};
```

and:

```
class DerivedClass1 : public AbstractClass {
public:
   DerivedClass() : AbstractClass() { m_Name = "DerivedClass1"; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the link error because the destructor for `AbstractClass` needs to be defined even if it is empty.

```
AbstractClass::~AbstractClass()
{
  // Compulsory virtual destructor definition,
  // even if it's empty
}
```

[LIVE on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KD6JW6pHVa7qixNf)

Regarding overriding `getName`: you do not have to. If you do not provide an implementation in the derived class, the one inherited one is used.

Comment: Okay. But I still want the Class to be Abstract. How do I achive this?

Comment: It is abstract already. if you try to declar an object of `AbstractClass ` type you will see that the compiler error will be pretty clear about it.

Comment: @HenningWilmer Abstractness just means that you have at least one pure virtual function. It's not something that code *requires*, it's something that *happens* because something in the class needs to be abstract. Based on your class's current needs (a GetName method and nothing else), your class is not yet abstract, but will likely become so (if needed) as you add actual functionality.

Comment: @DavideSpataro Okay thank you! It nearly worked for me. I am not getting an Error anymore, but neither do i get an output. Ah I see because m_Name of the AbstactClass is empty..

Answer (score 0):

Code sugest that problem is how to get a class name? But this is not clearly stated in question (XY problem)

How to handle class name?

You can use RTTI:

```
class ClassName {
public:
    virtual ~ClassName() {} // just to enable RTTI for all decendants

    std::string getClassName() {
        return typeid(*this).name();
    }
};
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/LvPdA37arMr0LFQW

But as you can see it adds some extra prefix (it is compiler depended). boost can clean it up:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/8XiB7yVOM0wYVxpl